# Pandas grouping with loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, pandas-groupby, average

is there a way to group a dataframe (*csv file) in these ways?
For example, I want to select blocks of ten rows for the first column to average and then I would like to do the same for the second column but not keeping blocks, but grouping every 10th row.
For ex. I want the average of:

```
1  1  3rd 4th
1  2  .. ..
1  3  .. ..
..
1  9  .. ..
1 10  .. ..
2  1  .. ..
2  2  .. ..
2  3  .. ..
```

So selecting the first chunk of the 1st column to calculate an average, and then every x rows for the second column.

For example, from a df like this one...

```
241888  1   1 
241888  2   1 
241888  3   2 
241888  4   2
241888  5   3 
241888  6   3
241888  7   4
241888  8   4
241888  9   5
241888  10  5 
665309  1   3
665309  2   3
665309  3   4
665309  4   4 
665309  5   5 
665309  6   5
665309  7   6 
665309  8   6 
665309  9   7 
665309  10  7
```

and then

```
df.groupby('24188').mean()[3]
df.groupby('665309').mean()[3]
df.groupby('1' of the 2nd column).mean()[3]
df.groupby('10' of the 2nd column).mean()[3]
```

giving 3, 5 2 and 6

Comment: could you please share the sample data frame with the sample output?

Comment: I tried to add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, if I did not get you properly. do you want this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5 ,6 , 7], 
'b': [11, 12, 13 , 14, 15 ,16 , 17], 
'c': [21, 22, 23 , 24, 25 ,26 , 27] } )
print(df)
print("sum of 1 st column with 2nd rows(i.e. 2,4,6):")
print(df.iloc[[x for x in df.index if (x+1) % 2 == 0],0].sum())

print("sum of 3rd column with 3rd rows(i.e. 22,36):")
print(df.iloc[[x for x in df.index if (x+1) % 3 == 0],2].sum())
```

output:

```
a   b   c
0  1  11  21
1  2  12  22
2  3  13  23
3  4  14  24
4  5  15  25
5  6  16  26
6  7  17  27
sum of 1 st column with 2nd rows(i.e. 2,4,6):
12
sum of 3rd column with 3rd rows(i.e. 22,36):
49
```

Comment: No, I would like to calculate averages over the 3rd column, for blocks of 10 rows (the identical values of the 1st columns) and every 10th row (the identical values for the 2nd row). But the *csv is really long so I have to do a loop, but I don't get how to do it with pandas.

Comment: if you are not making group by combining two columns then you can simply use this right ?
df.groupby('1st col').mean()['3rd column']--for first two result
df.groupby['2nd column'].mean()['3rd column'] then filter 1 and 10 --> for last two answer

Comment: I don't understand how can you evoke a column without a header. Do you write 'col2' for ex.?